# TortoiseSVN diff command in Msbuild

Tags: svn, msbuild, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net

I am using TortoiseSVN.
I would like to show differences for all files between the last revision and the current revision. For that I execute a script via msbuild.

Can you tell me how I can perform this diff command in order that I can compare all the files between the previous and the current revisions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the diff results?

Comment: It is very hard to tell what you're after. As it stands, you need to execute [`TortoiseProc.exe`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) or [`svn.exe diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re09.html) (if you installed the respective tools with TortoiseSVN). `TortoiseProc.exe` doesn't really make a whole lot of sense in an (automated, you mention CruiseControl.NET) build, because it can only show a GUI.

Comment: Difference  of all the file between two revision numbers. that's what i am expected from result.txt or result.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion here. I suspect that your are not using just TortoiseSVN, but some integrated SVN client (such as AnkhSVN) for MS VisualStudio as well. My answer below applied only to TortoiseSVN, not the integrated client.

It seems that you are trying to create a patch: right click on your root folder (i.e. the folder under which you want to compare all the files) -> create patch -> select all files you want to be diffed -> ok -> choose name -> save. The file thus created will contain all the differences between your working copy (WC) and the revision from which it was obtained. If you update your WC beforehand, it will contain the differences between your WC and the last revision.

To obtain all the differences between two committed revisions: right click on the root folder -> show log -> check the revisions you want to compare (by holding down the ctrl key and clicking on them -> right click -> show differences as unified diff. It will open a window with all the differences. You can then click File -> Save (or Save As).

Comment: I just want to save difference of text file data between two specific SVN revision numbers in TEXT or XML file.

Comment: Then I think that what I am proposing is exactly what you want.